# How do I redirect a page with Anonymizer link to the contained URL

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, greasemonkey, anonymous

Due to multiple scripts I have on the target domain I want to redirect the anonymized link directly to the page with a GreaseMonkey script:
Currently it does not work but my Javascript experience is outdated, so I need a little help.

Example with LinkBlur but other link anonymers should be same stuff:

http://linkblur.com/?http://www.yahoo.com

This is the script I tried to make but did not work:

```
var loc = window.location.href;
var reg = /[?](.*)/gi;
var correcturl = loc.match(reg).substring(1);
window.location = correcturl;
```

Thanks for the attention and please point out if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkBlur, and most of these sites, use frames or iFrames; your script must account for that.

Also it will crash frequently because the return from `match()` is not being checked properly.

This works:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  //-- Don't run on frames or iframes.
    return;

var loc         = window.location.href;
var correcturl  = loc.match (/\?(.+)/i);

if (correcturl  &&  correcturl[1]) {
    window.location = correcturl [1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think about the frame and iFrame problem, yes I didn't check for match exceptions, mine was first attempt to solve the problem.